# Prove that the Heaviside function has both left and right-hand limits at 0?

Tags: limits

Prove that the Heaviside function has both left and right-hand limits at 0?

I have no clue how to prove this. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Lets go with the left hand limit so maybe you be can solve the right hand.

The heavyside function is defined as

$$H(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    0       & \quad \text{if } x <0\\
    1  & \quad \text{if } x \geq 0\\
  \end{cases}
$$

So, let's show that the left hand side limit at $x = 0$ is $0$. By definition, you have to see that for any $\epsilon >0$ there exist $\delta >0$ such that $x \in (0-\delta,0)$ implies $|H(x)-0| < \epsilon$. But if $\delta$ is any positive number, for any $x \in (0-\delta,0)$ we have that $H(x)=0$ and therfore, for any $\epsilon >0$, any $\delta >0$ will work.

Can you calculate the right hand side limit?

Comment: @ Joaquin Liniado Please let me know if my second part works.

Comment: @Tmm Please do not edit answer for your further work - you could put it in your own question as an update. Edit are not supposed to change author's original intention.